# Forcing auto to be a reference type in a range for loop

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, range, auto

Suppose I have `foo` which is a populated `std::vector<double>`.

I need to operate on the elements of this vector. I'm motivated to write

```
for (auto it : foo){
   /*ToDo - Operate on 'it'*/
}
```

But it appears that this will not write back to `foo` since `it` is a value type: a deep copy of the vector element has been taken.

Can I give some guidance to `auto` to make `it` a reference type? Then I could operate directly on `it`.

I suspect I'm missing some trivial syntax.

Comment: This is a very basic question. Something like "how do I declare an integer in C++". You should read a [book on C++ basics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead of asking the question because I fear you will have thousands more if you don't. I would close this question as "lacks minimum understanding" but I lack the rep for that and the close reason has been removed.

Comment: A very basic question? The questions I used to ask my general relativity professor were probably considered by him to be basic. This question seems quite advanced to me.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**A minimal `auto` reference**

The loop can be declared as follows:

```
for (auto& it : foo) {
   //    ^ the additional & is needed
   /*ToDo - Operate on 'it'*/
}
```

This will allow `it` to be a reference to each element in `foo`.

There is some debate as to the "canonical form" of these loops, but the `auto&` should do the trick in this case.

**General `auto` reference**

In a more general sense (outside the specifics of the container), the following loop works (and may well be preferable).

```
for (auto&& it : container) {
   //    ^ && used here
}
```

The `auto&&` allows for bindings to lvalues and rvalues. When used in a generic or general (e.g. template situation) this form may strike the desired balance (i.e. references, copies, prvalue/xvalue returns (e.g. proxy objects) etc.).

Favour the general `auto&&`, but if you have to be specific about the form, then use a more specific variation (e.g. `auto`, `auto const&` etc.).

**Why is `auto&&` better?**

As noted in other answers here and the comments. Why is `auto&&` better? Simply it will do what you think it should in most cases, see [this proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3853.htm) and [its update](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3994.htm).

As always, Scott Meyers' [blog](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) about this also makes for a good read.

Comment: That's perfect. So in many respects it works in a similar way to template specialisations.

Comment: `auto&&` is preferable.

Comment: Because it precisely mirrors the const/rvalue/whatever semantics of the iterator.

Comment: @YogiBear, `auto` as used by you in the loop follows template type deduction rules.

Comment: @YogiBear: to manage proxy as in `std::vector<bool>` for example

Comment: @Puppy, As I noted, there is some debate. Not that I disagree, just the single `&` would be the minimum required for the operation as described.

Comment: For those wondering why `auto&&` is preferable, I highly suggest reading Scott Meyers article on Universal References: http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers Basically, `auto&&` will become `auto&` when necessary, but also allows for the r-value optimization of `auto&&`

Comment: @AndyG, that is a great read. I find myself coming back to that article often.

Answer (score 22):

I would use `auto&&`:

```
for (auto&& it : foo) {
    // bla
}
```

The reason is spelt out in [**N3994**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3994.htm) "*Range-Based For-Loops: The Next Generation (Revision 1)*" that it would better work with **proxy objects** (such as those coming from `std::vector<bool>`).

In fact, that proposal for C++1z (supported already by Clang 3.5 SVN in `-std=c++1z` mode) proposes the syntax:

```
// c++1z only
for (it : foo) { 
    // bla
}
```

as a short-hand for `for (auto&& it : foo)`.

**Update**: the N3994 proposal was [not voted into](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4251.html) the C++17 working paper.

Comment: As I tryed no-type syntax is not work with clang anymore (tested on 3.6 and above). [live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/qXhUXc2KQN6iq6wY)

Comment: @alexolut yes, this info is now outdated as the N3994 was [not voted into C++17](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4251.html). The implementations present in earlier versions of clang, gcc and msvc have been removed.

Answer (score 5):

You may use:

```
for (auto&& it : foo){

}
```

`auto &&` is prefered to `auto &` to manage proxy iterator as for `std::vector<bool>`.

Answer (score 5):

In many ways this confusion is arising from the convention that's grown up over the years to bind a `*` or a `&` to the type as opposed to the variable.

For example `int* a` is really `int *a`; i.e. `a` is a pointer to a value of type `int`.

The same applies to references: in the case of `int& a`, `a` is a reference to a value of type `int`.

So what you really want to do is write `for (auto &it : foo)` so `it` is a reference to the type inferred by `auto`. Then you can use `it` to manipulate the underlying vector elements. More often than not this will be written as

`for (auto& it : foo)`

Moving forward, you might want to use an **r-value reference**: `for (auto&& it : foo)` which is probably the best general form.