# Is it possible to iterate over an iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator

I have a working program that capitalizes strings in a vector, using iterators:

```
vector<string> v7{ 10, "apples" };  

for (auto vIterator= v7.begin(); vIterator!= v7.end(); ++vIterator){
    auto word = *vIterator; //here
    auto charIterator = word.begin(); 
    *charIterator = toupper(*charIterator);
    *vIterator = word; //also here, i guess i could just print `word` instead?
    cout << *vIterator << endl;
}
```

My question is;
2nd line inside the loop @ the comment, i had to save the `pointer to the iterator` to another `string variable` before i was able to iterate over it.

Iterating over the pointer like so

```
*vIterator.begin();
```

didn't seem to work.


Is this the correct practice, or am i missing something?
 I'm new to the C languages, the concept behind pointer-like tools is quite hard to understand even if i can use them, and in this case it just feels like I'm doing it wrong.

**Edit: It was a syntax error (*vIterator).begin();**
It just didn't make sense why i'd have to save it to another variable before iterating over it, cheers.

Comment: If by "didn't seem to work", you meant gave you a compiler error, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: @chris, I took it back, sorry, was reading it incorrectly.

Comment: Make sure to accurately describe the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using C++11 look how simpler your code can become using ranged loops like the example below:

```
  std::vector<std::string> v(10, "apples");  
  for(auto &&word : v) {
    word[0] = toupper(word[0]);
  }
```

[<kbd>**LIVE DEMO**</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b13dbaabab6591c)

Now as far as it concerns the (`*vIterator.begin();` didn't seem to work.):

- The dot operator (i.e., `.`) has a higher precedence than the dereference operator (i.e., `*`). Thus, `*vIterator.begin()` is interpreted as `*(vIterator.begin())`. The compiler rightfully complains because `vIterator` hasn't got a member `begin()`.
- Think of iterators as if they were pointers. The correct way to access the members of an object via a pointer/iterator pointing to it is either using the arrow operator (i.e., `vIterator->begin()`) or first dereference the pointer/iterator and then use the dot operator (i.e., `(*vIterator).begin()`).

So your code via the use of iterators would become:

```
  std::vector<std::string> v(10, "apples");  
  for(auto it(v.begin()), ite(v.end()); it != ite; ++it) {
    *(it->begin()) = toupper(*(it->begin()));
  }
```

[<kbd>**LIVE DEMO**</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/80cf21e305abfd1b)

Comment: Definitely, but i insisted on iterators for learning purposes :)

Comment: Why are you capturing `v` by r-value reference? Why would you not do `for(auto & word : v)`? I need to become more familiar with when to throw in the `&&` other than for move construction/destruction...

Comment: @user2899162 It's more of a common practice to use universal references in ranged loops when you want to change the elements of the container you are iterating. Using universal references with a range-based loop has the advantage of what you are capturing will always be `*it`. More on this can be read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25158976/forcing-auto-to-be-a-reference-type-in-a-range-for-loop)

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to write `*vIterator.begin();` is `(*vIterator).begin();` or, more often, `vIterator->begin();`.  Also note that you can also access the first character of a string directly (without having to iterate over it) as `word[0]`.

Comment: @user2357112: Right; fixed.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `STL`-ish way of doing it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> v7{ 10, "apples" };  
    for_each(v7.begin(), v7.end(), [](string& word){word[0] = toupper(word[0]);});
}
```